# Google sheets Index and Match with Multiple Criteria based on user input

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table in Google Sheets with multiple advertising channels, their spend, value generated and return on investment (ROI). I'm trying to create an excel formula where a user can put in their target ROI and I return the first row data for each channel that is equal to or more than the set ROI. So for example, using the table below, ***if the target is 400%, I return data for row `A5` for Google, `A4` for Twitter and `A2` for FB.***

| Channel | Spend | Value | Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google | $30 | $50 | 167% |
| FB | $40 | $100 | 250% |
| Twitter | $50 | $150 | 300% |
| Twitter | $70 | $224 | 320% |
| Google | $80 | $320 | 400% |
| FB | $90 | $450 | 450% |

So far, I'm using Index and Match to return each cell where the ROI condition is true. If user puts in target return in `M9` for example

```
=INDEX(A2:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(D2:D>=M9,0),0))
```

But this only returns the first row that matches the ROI condition irrespective of channel, I want to add a second condition for channel. That way, I can return something like

| Channel | Spend | Value | Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google | $80 | $320 | 400% |
| FB | $40 | $100 | 250% |
| Twitter | $70 | $224 | 320% |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use query

```
=query(A:D,"select * where D>="&F1&" ")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This put me on the right track. I modified to the below to avoid picking all instances where the condition was true and only pick the first instance by channel `=IFERROR(query(A2:D,"select B,C,D where D>="&F1&" AND A contains 'Google' LIMIT 1"),"No available scenarios")` I have one of such queries per channel and this works perfectly for me.